# Auto-login to aws ec2 instance running windows on startup

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run a service on startup of a windows instance on amazon. So far it is a manual process where I have to start rdp in, log in and then start the process. I'd like it when the instance loads for us to be able to bypass the login so it can go straight to the desktop and load a process.

The only thing I've tried that allowed me to get somewhat close is to setup SSH on the server and have a shell script that automatically logs me in and starts the process. I'd like a way to do it through AWS settings though. Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you just change Autostart status of that service from `Manual` to `Automatic`?

Comment: I suppose I could

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that it is a full-fledged Windows service you need to start, then it's as simple as @Mxx points out: just set the service startup type to Automatic rather than Manual.

If it's not a service but just a regular Windows process, then you can look into using [Sysinternals Autologon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963905.aspx) to cause the instance to automatically log in as a particular user when it boots, and then the normal ways of running things at startup (the [Startup group in the Start Menu](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7), the [Run and RunOnce keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx) in the registry, etc.) will function as you expect.